# How to compare an Array List with mobile Contact

Tags: android, arraylist, android-contacts

I have an array list.

1) my first `ArrayList<String> some_num = new ArrayList<String>();` which contain the value like this.

```
[1111111111, 2222222222]
```

Now I am trying to compare this with my mobile contact like this.

```
  Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
  String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

                Cursor people = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

                int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int j_count=0;
                String number;
                people.moveToFirst();
                do {

                    String name   = people.getString(indexName);
                     number = people.getString(indexNumber);
                    j_count++;


                    // Do work...
                } while (people.moveToNext());




                for(int j=0;j<=j_count;j++){

                    if (some_num.contains(number)){
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else{
                    Log.e("num",number);
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to get those number which is not present in my ArrayList from the mobile phone book. I know that in for condition i have to get the value of array but when i try to do this i am not getting the rest of my contact.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in this code, Any exception or any error?

Comment: no i am getting only one single contact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dont use any other loop to compare the numbers. What's wrong with your code then?

You are comparing your array with `number` variable which holds the last number reference. because of which your are getting only single result.

if your still want to use your code then create another arrayList in which you store all the number like this:

```
ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and to add the number in this list use below line before j++;

```
numberList.add(number);
```

Now update your last iterator block to work like this:

```
       for(int j=0;j<numberList.siz();j++){

            if (some_num.contains(numberList.get(i)){
                // do nothing 
            } 
            else{ 
            Log.e("num",numberList.get(i));
            } 
        }
```

To get complete detail of User you can create the Model class which contains the user details like this:

```
public class UserDetails{
    private String userName;
    private String userPhone;
    private String userImage;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPhone() {
        return userPhone;
    }

    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
    }

    public String getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(String userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }
}
```

Now you have to use this model in your activity to get and set the details of user:

```
ArrayList<UserDetails> mUserDetailList = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
```

and to get the contacts name use this code:

```
  String name   = people.getString(indexName);
```

now store name and phonenumber like this:

```
UserDetails mUserModel = new UserDetails();

mUserModel.setUserPhone(number);
mUserModel.setUserName(name);

mUserDetailList.add(mUserModel);
```

Now to check whether the number exists or not:

```
 for(int j=0;j<mUserDetailList.siz();j++){
 
            if (some_num.contains(mUserDetailList.get(i).getUserPhone()){ 
                // do nothing  
            }  
            else{  
            Log.e("num",numberList.get(i).getUserPhone());
            Log.e("name",numberList.get(i).getUserName());
            }  
        }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Anjali for your valuable answer. but when i am trying to use solution so i am getting the Exception at "if condtion"

Comment: Exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3 it is coming here try {
                            if (mysql_ar.contains(numberList.get(j))) {
                                // do nothing
                            } else {
                                Log.e("num", numberList.get(j));
                            }
                        }catch (Exception ex){}

Comment: update your code  so that we will check whats wrong with the code

Comment: check now. there was issue in If statement. Now it will work without exception

Comment: thanks @Anjali thanks for the help it is perfectly work now.Great and thank u very much.

Comment: thanks @Anjali this is the correct answer but now i am facing the problem that how to get name of those user in "else condition".here we are getting the number only Log.e("num",numberList.get(i));

Comment: awesome @Anjali u r great. thanks alot. some up vote for u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95673/discussion-between-shubhank-gupta-and-anjali).

Answer (score 1):

One ideal solution could be to use a **hasp map**.

Store the entire contact in a hash map as the key
and check if your list has those number by simply trying to put the value to the hash map.

This will work as hash map wont have duplicatesand when u try to insert a duplicate key you will know that

**EDIT**
I think your code might work with this fix

```
               String number;
                people.moveToFirst();
                do {

                    String name   = people.getString(indexName);
                     number = people.getString(indexNumber);
                 // for(int j=0;j<=j_count;j++){

                    if (some_num.contains(number)){
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else{
                    Log.e("num",number);
                    //}
                    j_count++;


                    // Do work...
                } while (people.moveToNext());





                }
```

Comment: Thanks @Abx actually i am thinking to use the hash map or collection but I newer used it before can you plz give me more idea how to use that

Comment: @Abx even your code is wrong. What is the need of iterating over j if your are comparing the current number?

Comment: @Abx but if you look into the code he define j_count to get the size of phone contacts . he is not taking the length of contacts array which he is getting from server.

Answer (score 1):

try as follows and dont forget to clear the list when ever reusing it

```
ArrayList<String>  list = new ArrayList<String>();

 people.moveToFirst();
                do {

                    String name   = people.getString(indexName);
                     number = people.getString(indexNumber);
                     list.add(number);
                    j_count++;


                    // Do work...
                } while (people.moveToNext());

for(String str:list)
{

  if(yournumber.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
{ 
    //do your stuff
}

}
```

Comment: thanks @venkatesh for your answer but i have one doubt is that in "if condition " you are giving one variable is yournumber but in my question yournumber is an array list is i compare it like this?

Comment: Nopes,its depend on what u have to compare.The list have all numbers what your are reading from cursor and in for loop u can compare each and evry item in the list